# jQuery keyup firing many times until released

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought `keyup` can only fire once, until the key is released. Well in this instance it fires on `keydown`, unlimited times, until released.

It is refreshing the search until key is released, then tries to catch up. I want a user to be able to hit enter to fire the "search" button.

Is my `keyup` function missing some sort of timer or limiter? User input values in textbox + hit enter + should search a list for matches.

```
// keyup for enter search
// is working perfectly if I hit enter and relsease 1 time
$( '#TextBoxDiv' + lastChar ).on( 'keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        $("#searchButton").click();
     }
});

// search function
$( '#searchButton' ).click( function () {
    RebuildResultsTable();
} );
```

Comment: Seems to work okay here: http://jsfiddle.net/eGMbM/ What is `lastChar`?

Comment: works okay for me as well http://jsfiddle.net/Hn5Az/

Comment: @SimonAdcock remember to add jQuery but yes it seems it's working

Comment: As @SimonAdcock shows it is always a very good idea to do a Fiddle demo ;-) Both to get yourself thinking but also to make it easier for people to give the correct answer

Comment: Works here too: http://jsfiddle.net/9qL7q/ ... It must not be due to the keyup. More likely the problem is in your selector.

Comment: @EduardoQuintana Good spot, forgot to update :)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddles. Interestingly enough, the keyup functionality ran only on enter keyup (correctly) on another computer. Original problem was on an external Dell keyboard, no problem on laptop keyboard. Strange!